How to represent $\cos\theta \sin\phi$ as a linear combination or expansion of spherical harmonics?
I have for the boundary condition of some PDE in spherical coordinates: $$U(\theta,\phi) = \cos\theta\sin\phi$$
Spherical harmonics are represented as $$\tag{1}Y_l^m = \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}\frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}}P_l^m(\cos\theta)e^{im\phi}$$
And a spherical harmonic expansion representation of a function is:
$$\tag{2} f(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^l a_{l,m}Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) \\ a_{l,m} = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi f(\theta,\phi)Y_{l}^{m*}\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$
$\cos\theta = P_1^0 (\cos\theta) \therefore l = 1, m = 0$
$\sin\phi = \frac{e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}}{2i} \therefore |l|\ge m,m = \pm 1$
$$\tag{3}\cos\theta\sin\phi = \frac{1}{2i}\Big(P_1^0 (\cos\theta)e^{i\phi}\Big) - \frac{1}{2i}\Big(P_1^0(\cos\theta)e^{-i\phi}\Big)$$
and because $|l|\ge 1$ must be true for $\sin\phi$ and is not true for the Legendre polynomial representation of $\cos\theta$, then neither of the 2 terms in(3) can be represented by a spherical harmonic (SEE TABLE).

(3) is not the spherical harmonic expansion that you get from (2). If you compute the coefficients $a_{l,m}$ defined in (2), you will notice that they are nonzero for $m=\pm1$ and $l=2,4,6,\ldots$.

There's a typo in your formula for $\sin\phi$ in terms of exponentials: the denominator should be $2i$.

There's also typo in the definition of $a_{l,m}$: there shouldn't be any summation and the indices on $Y$ should be $l$ and $m$.

@Pranay How do I compute the coefficients $a_{l,m}$ if due to orthogonality, the integral is 0 for all spherical harmonic representations of $f(\theta,\phi)$ for $l\ne l'$ and $m \ne m'$? Or rather, the issue is I cannot figure out how to create a spherical harmonic representation to plug into $f(\theta,\phi)$ in this integral to get my coefficients, that's what I was asking to begin with if it wasn't clear. I don't see how you got representations for $m=\pm 1$ and $l=2,4,6,...$

I don't understand what you mean by "$l\ne l'$ and $m\ne m'$". The LHS has indices $l$ and $m$, so the RHS should also have indices $l$ and $m$, not $l'$ and $m'$. See the definition of $f_{lm}$ in this link for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Spherical_harmonics_expansion

Once you have the definition of $a_{lm}$ right, all you need to do is substitute $f(\theta,\phi) = \cos\theta\sin\phi$ into the integral, and compute the integral for various values of $l$ and $m$. You will get a nonzero answer for $m=\pm 1$ and $l=2,4,6,\ldots$.

@Pranay I'm using the ' notation in line with what I saw for the orthogonality property here. Testing it out, yes the convolution of $f(\theta,\phi)$ with a (complex conjugate) spherical harmonic for those values of $l$ do work. What I'd like to know is how you're determining those values of $l$? Are you plugging in values at random and checking to see if the resulting integrand in nonzero, or what exactly are you doing?

I didn't determine the values of $l$ arbitrarily. First, it is easy to see why you need $m=\pm1$. Then, since $f$ has a factor of $\cos \theta$, and the integrand already has a $\sin \theta$, you get a nonzero answer if and only if $Y_l^m$ has a $\sin\theta$ times odd powers of $\cos\theta$. This is true precisely for $l=2,4,6,\ldots$.

I think you should think more carefully about the indices in the second line of (2). As written now, it's not correct. The RHS should have $l$ and $m$.

@Pranay Oh okay, I can see what you're talking about in incorporating $\sin\theta$ which naturally arises in the integrand when performing spherical polar integration into our function $f(\theta,\phi)$, but I thought we needed that $\sin\theta$ in order to satisfy the orthogonality relationship to begin with. $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)Y_{l'}^{m'*}\sin\theta d\theta d\phi = \delta(l-l')\delta(m-m')$$.

@Pranay I hope I'm making sense here, but the idea (which I think you picked up on as well) was to take $f(\theta,\phi)$ and try to write it in terms of $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$ and then evaluating this integral becomes much easier because we've then recreated the orthogonality integral above. I wasn't sure how to create that spherical harmonic representation, however incorporating $\sin\theta$ allowed us to create one, and Curiously though, merging that $\sin\theta$ into our function and using it to create a spherical harmonic representation did not effect getting a nonzero result, so it did work

@Pranay or well it did work "if and only if $Y_l^m$ has a $\sin\theta$ times odd powers of $\cos\theta$" as you pointed out. Interesting. I guess getting spherical harmonic representations of functions wasn't quite as rigid and inflexible as I had originally thought.
